# Where to put Java Simple Captcha Builder?

Tags: java, jsp, captcha, simplecaptcha

I am a newbie at java/java servlet. I need the simpleCaptcha for a form, using html and javaservlet for the code. With reference to `http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/extending.html`.

```
Captcha captcha = new Captcha.Builder(200, 50)
    .addText()
    .addBackground()
    .addNoise()
    .gimp()
    .addBorder()
    .build(); // Required.
```

Where (java servlet) should I put this piece of code in order to create the captcha on html?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To extend SimpleCaptcha and customize your CAPTCHA, my understanding is that you'll have to create your own `HttpServlet` (maybe extends `SimpleCaptchaServlet`). To do so, I suggest to download the [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplecaptcha/files/SimpleCaptcha/1.1.1/SimpleCaptcha-1.1.1-src.zip/download) and to look at `SimpleCaptchaServlet` or `StickyCaptchaServlet`. This is what the `doGet()` method of `SimpleCaptchaServlet` looks like:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Captcha captcha = new Captcha.Builder(_width, _height)
        .addText()
        .addBackground(new GradiatedBackgroundProducer())
        .gimp()
        .addNoise()
        .addBorder()
        .build();

    CaptchaServletUtil.writeImage(resp, captcha.getImage());

    req.getSession().setAttribute(NAME, captcha);
}
```

This should be self-explaining: create your own servlet and put your custom Captcha Builder code in the `doGet()` method. Then, follow the instructions of the [Installing](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/installing.html) section but, instead of using one of their servlet, declare yours in the `web.xml`. Finally, package/deploy your application. An example is bundled in the source distribution under `examples`. Check it out if you need more guidance about the structure, the dependencies and the packaging of your web application.

Answer (score 2):

hey have you had a look at this page yet?
http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/installing.html

this is about as straight forward as it gets I think.  This project gives you a few Capcha servlets out of the box.  You just have to map them in your web.xml file.  You can follow along and create the jsp that will call them.

Comment: @darren: Hi, thanks for replying. I saw that link you have provided with but then that is the example for Sticky Captcha, which needs to include session, and there isn't customization. I only need a Simple Captcha, and some customization on the captcha image using its builder. Moreover, I really need help to put that in a servlet, as my validation portion are all in a servlet, instead of jsp.